# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'delegate'

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

It's work fine on chrome or firefox but it's not working on ie8

```
    a(".contextual-help-tabs").delegate("a","click focus",function(d){
    var c=a(this),b;
    d.preventDefault();
    if(c.is(".active a")){
        return false
        }
a(".contextual-help-tabs .active").removeClass("active");
c.parent("li").addClass("active");
b=a(c.attr("href"));
a(".help-tab-content").not(b).removeClass("active").hide();
b.addClass("active").show()
});
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting in the console, press F12 before loading the page..

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method

Although `.delegate` is still there and should work, you should use `.on` instead:

```
a(".contextual-help-tabs").on("click focus", "a", function(d) {
  ...
});
```